# Find distance on the side of polygon to create angle

Tags: trigonometry, polygons

I'm trying to develop an application (with programming languages) where I can create 6 sided polygons with the same angle, wich is 60º deg, for example, to create the sides, like the image below. The only thing I know is the height of this object and the angle to be used.

This is an example of the result I expect to achieve:

[image]

Is there a formula to calculate the distance the point needs to be from the left side to achieve that angle? See image below.

[image]

I want to be able to change the height of the element, but keep the proportion of the polygon in all elements, wich is 60º.

I tried to use this formula, but it's not working:

$$x = tan(60º) * h$$

Comment: It seems that you are trying to draw an hexagon. So the angle should be $120°$.

Comment: @Axel I've updated my question with an image of how I expect the shape to be.

Comment: @JeanMarie Are you not calculating the hypothenuse instead? I might be wrong, but I have half your result.

Comment: Does my quick sketch help you with your problem, or do you need something more specific? Or more general?

Comment: @Axel : you are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this is what I did, it gives you $x = 20/\sqrt{3}$.

[image: Here is what I did]

So more generally for a $n$-agon then you have the angle $\alpha = 180°-360°/n$ (on the sketch $\alpha = 120°$) and therefore $x = \tan((180°-\alpha)/2) \times \frac{h}{2}$ hence:

$$\boxed{x = \tan\left(\frac{180°}{n}\right)\times \frac{h}{2}}$$

Comment: I've made those edits you also did on the answer. For me, when I was using the formula as code to program, I had to create one more step. But in general, this solve my issue. I'll have to put it to test with more and more shapes, But I think I got it! Very nice!

Comment: @celsomtrindade I'm glad it helped!